# C++ constructor invocation

Tags: c++

The following invokes one instance of the constructor followed by the destructor of `A` (vs. invoking copy or move constructors). Is this an optimization that only one instance of `A` is created, or is this behavior mandated by the standard?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    A() { 
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";
    }
    ~A() { 
        std::cout << "Destructor\n";
    }
    A (const A&) = delete;
};

int main() { 
    A a{A{A{A{A{}}}}};
}
```

Comment: From C++17, it is **mandated**. Read about copy elision. Look at `T x = T(T(f()));` example given [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)